# How to dynamically switch between hash algorithms in golang?

Tags: hash, go

I want to be able to switch between hash algorithms depending on caller input, for example, implement a function:

```
func GenericHash(dat []byte, hash unint) (string, error) { ... }
```

where hash is the algorithm type as specified by [crypto.Hash](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Hash).

I'm not sure how to write this function, in particular, where the import statements should go. If I include all the import statements for algorithms that I will use at the top, go complains that they're imported and not used. Is there anyway to import on demand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is [import the packages for their side effects only](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_import) (i.e. use the blank identifier when importing the packages). This means that the imported packages' `init` functions will be executed, but you will not be able to access any of their exported members directly.

Here is one way you could solve your problem:

```
import (
  "errors"
  "encoding/hex"
  "crypto"
  _ "crypto/md5"
  _ "crypto/sha1"
  // import more hash packages
)

func GenericHash(dat []byte, hash crypto.Hash) (string, error) {
  if !hash.Available() {
    return "", errors.New("hash unavailable")
  }
  h := hash.New()
  return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(dat)), nil
}
```

Comment: I just checked this again and I don't think `h.Sum(dat)` would do it, I don't get the same result if I call the function directly like `sha256.Sum256(dat)`. The example [sha1.New()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/#example_New) mentions adding the string before calling `Sum`.